# error while calling a rest webservice

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I have a rest webservice which returns `java.util.List<String>`. Please see the code below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = MyRequestMapping.GET_SIG_DATA, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<String> getSigDataValues(@PathVariable final String acc, final HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {

        List<String> dataList = null;
        try {
             //logic goes here
        } catch (Exception e) {
             LOG.error("Exception" + e);
        }
        return dataList;
    }
```

The above webservice is not returning any responseDTO object, it just returns a list of String type.

I want to call above webservice from another application.Below is my code.

```
 public List<String> getSigData(String acc){

       return restTemplate.postForObject(DataURL.GET_SIG_DATA.value(), MyRequestDTO.class,MyResponseDTO.class, acc);
}
```

When compiling its throwing the below error message:

```
[javac] found   : com.data.client.MyRequestDTO
[javac] required: java.util.List<String>
[javac]        return restTemplate.postForObject(DataURL.GET_SIG_DATA.value(), MyRequestDTO.class,MyResponseDTO.class,acc);
                                       ^
```

Please suggest where i am going wrong.

Comment: the return type of restTemplate.postForObject is different than List<String>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 public List<String> getSigData(String acc){

       return (List<String>)restTemplate.postForObject(DataURL.GET_SIG_DATA.value(), List.class,List.class, acc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
return restTemplate.postForObject(DataURL.GET_SIG_DATA.value(),List.class,null, acc);
```

Please refer to 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#postForObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object...-